# Skip only Non ASCII character with read.table

Tags: r, csv, encoding, iconv, read.table

I have a csv file with Non ASCII characteres in it. I simply want to remove that characters and read my csv file.

```
> tables <- lapply('/.././abc.csv', read.csv,header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,fileEncoding="UTF-8")
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  invalid input found on input connection '/.././abc.csv'
> df= suppressWarnings(do.call(rbind, tables))
```

It is not reading the complete file. It has only read the records before the Non-ASCII character. It has skipped all the records after Non ASCII chracter.

I cannot use `iconv('/.././abc.csv', "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")` as it expects x as vector.

```
cat '/.././abc.csv'
88036,120,151036.656250,2017-07-17 22:27:49,17-07-17 22:27:49
88036,120,151036.671875,2017-07-17 22:27:53,17-07-17 22:27:53
88036,310,151036.687500,2017-07-17 22:27:58,17-07-17 22:27:58
88036,310,151036.703▒▒F▒▒B▒▒▒D▒%▒▒▒2▒T▒▒K222642,17-07-17 22:28:03,2017-07-17 22:28:03
88036,310,151036.484375,2017-07-17 22:26:54,17-07-17 22:26:54
88036,310,151036.500000,2017-07-17 22:26:59,17-07-17 22:26:59
```

It is skipping last 2 records after reading the CSV files. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

What if you read it first and then you do

`td <- td[,lapply(.SD,function(x){ iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")})]`

assuming that you read your csv file as a `data.table`